# rsyslog performance optimization

Tags: php, mysql, performance, logging, rsyslog

**What should be done to setup [rsyslog](http://www.rsyslog.com/) for best performance?**

- We can allow some items to be lost on server crash or just lost.
- We are going to save logs to the MySQL DB.
- We would like to be able to handle at least 100 log writes per second with latency 0.001 - 0.005 second.
- We are writing logs from PHP application.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 7):

We just went through a similar exercise using MongoDB as the database, so I'll document what we did and hope it helps you.

It was our first time using rsyslog, so it took a bit of effort to find the right documentation and piece everything together.  In the end, our test drivers (we're using SoapUI) are able to get 1000 TPS through a php web service that uses rsyslog to write a summary record of the transaction.

We found the following articles that got us started:

- http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_high_database_rate.html
- http://www.rsyslog.com/tag/mongodb/

The overview is that you'll enable rsyslog's queue infrastructure for writing incoming messages to disk when the daemon's memory queue is full.  In our case, we enabled $ActionQueueSaveOnShutdown, which it sounds like you don't need.  Then you'll configure the rsyslog ruleset to parse the incoming messages and pass them to an output handler for MySQL.  Finally, your php script will use openlog() and syslog() to write whatever data you want to log.  Oh, we also had to compile rsyslog from source, in order to enable the json/mongo plugins, and that was an exercise in itself.  We're using rsyslog 7.4.5 on Ubuntu 12.04.

I'm certainly not an expert on rsyslog, however can give you our config files and code as a starting point.  Again, they're for MongoDB, hopefully it gives you an idea of what to do and where to change things for your implementation.

Good luck!

/etc/rsyslog.conf:

```
$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging
$ModLoad imklog   # provides kernel logging support (previously done by rklogd)

# Load modules for MongoDB integration: json parser and MongoDB output driver
module(load="mmjsonparse")
module(load="ommongodb")

# Use traditional timestamp format.
# To enable high precision timestamps, comment out the following line.
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

# Filter duplicated messages
$RepeatedMsgReduction on

# Set the default permissions for all log files.
$FileOwner syslog
$FileGroup adm
$FileCreateMode 0640
$DirCreateMode 0755
$Umask 0022
$PrivDropToUser syslog
$PrivDropToGroup syslog

# Where to place spool files
$WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog

# use queue to decouple the db writes from default message handling
# From http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_high_database_rate.html
$MainMsgQueueFileName mainq     # set file name for main queue, also enables disk mode
$ActionQueueType LinkedList     # use asynchronous processing
$ActionQueueFileName mongodbq   # set file name for mongo db queue, enables disk mode
$ActionResumeRetryCount -1      # infinite retries on insert failure
$ActionQueueSaveOnShutdown on   # write all queue data to disk when rsyslogd is
                                #   terminated (default is off)

# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf
```

/etc/rsyslog.d/10-mongo.conf:

```
input(type="imuxsock" socket="/dev/log")

template(name="mongodblocal" type="subtree" subtree="$!")

# use json parser for all "local0" facility messages, 
# if parsed successfully run the template to load the
# message into the MongoDB database.
if $syslogfacility-text == 'local0' then {
        action(type="mmjsonparse")
        if $parsesuccess == "OK" then {
                # set some local vars that are appended onto the 
                # document that's written to MongoDB
                set $!time = $timestamp;
                set $!sys = $hostname;
                set $!procid = $syslogtag;
                set $!syslog_fac = $syslogfacility;
                set $!syslog_sever = $syslogpriority;
                set $!pid = $procid;
                action(type="ommongodb" server="127.0.0.1" db="test" collection="syslog" template="mongodblocal")
        }
}
```

/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf:  Note: this disables "local0" messages for default handling.

```
# First some standard log files.  Log by facility.
auth,authpriv.*         /var/log/auth.log

# don't write "local0" messages to syslog, 
# as they're processed using ommongodb (see 10-mongo.conf)
*.*;local0,auth,authpriv.none   -/var/log/syslog

kern.*              -/var/log/kern.log
mail.*              -/var/log/mail.log

# Logging for the mail system.  Split it up so that
# it is easy to write scripts to parse these files.
mail.err            /var/log/mail.err

# Logging for INN news system.
news.crit           /var/log/news/news.crit
news.err            /var/log/news/news.err
news.notice         -/var/log/news/news.notice

# Emergencies are sent to everybody logged in.
*.emerg                                :omusrmsg:*
```

php web service related calls:

```
// open syslog, include the process ID and open the connection to the logger 
// immediately, and use a user defined logging mechanism Local0
openlog($SCRIPT_NAME, LOG_PID | LOG_NDELAY, LOG_LOCAL0);
// note: calling closelog() is optional, and we don't use it

...
// construct $doc, which is what will be logged, change this as appropriate
// for your implementation; here $ary_headers is the request's HTTP headers,
// and $request/$response are what was posted/returned
$doc = array("headers" => $ary_headers
            ,"request" => $request
            ,"response" => $response
            );
...

// write the log entry to syslog, where it queues it and writes it to MongoDB
// NOTE: need the '@cee: ' prefix so the rsyslog json parser will process it
// See:  http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf_modules.html/mmjsonparse.html

// JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING = Encodes large integers as their original string value.
// JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK = Encodes numeric strings as numbers.
// JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES = Don't escape "/".

syslog(LOG_INFO, '@cee: ' . json_encode($doc, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help, even though it's about Elasticsearch, not MySQL:
http://blog.sematext.com/2014/01/20/rsyslog-8-1-elasticsearch-output-performance/

But it explains the basics of how rsyslog works with queues and threads, and you have a new-style configuration that you can start with. Plus links that send you to rsyslog's documentation about queues, rulesets, etc.

For more info on the new-style config format, this is a good resource: http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rainerscript.html